# WinSCP: wait at `searching for host` page

Tags: networking, centos, vmware-workstation, winscp

When I try to connect my Centos running on VMWare, WinSCP wait in `searching for host` line and do not connect.
I've checked that SSH is up and running on port 22 of my VMWare and turned off windows firewall for checking, but WinSCP still do not connects to Centos on VMWare.

Comment: Please retag with the correct program. E.g. [tag:vmware-player]. or [tag:vmware-workstation], or [tag:esx]. The tag vmware itself is way to broad and has been replaced.

Answer (score 0):

The problems caused by `iptables` which did not allow ssh to get through. Turning of iptables (which is risky in production environment) or changing its configuration to allow ssh traffic pass through will fix this thing. 
Turning off iptables (**risky as noted in production environment**):

```
[root@MYHOST ~]# /etc/init.d/iptables stop
```